# How to embed a date object in @Query Spring Data JPA without passing an argument in interface method

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, spring-el

I have an interface which extends `CrudRepository` (for `spring-data-jpa` integration).

Lets assume I have a method and I wanted to do something like below.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserData u set u.lastUpdatedDate = #{new Date()}, u.lastUpdatedBy = ?2, lock=true where u.userId = ?1");
public void lockUser(Long userId, User updatingUser);
```

Now I have two questions

1. I don't want to pass a `lastUpdatedDate` in every function instead wanted to make use of `SpEL` to dynamically create a date object and pass.
2. Let's say if I wanted to skip passing the `updatingUser` argument by using a `default` function in interface can `Spring EL` support that? If yes how?

`default` function meaning something like this.

```
public interface myInterface extends CrudRepository<T,ID>{
    default UserDetails getAdminObj(){
        UserDetails systemAccount= new UserDetails();
        systemAccount.setUserID(-120);
        return systemAccount;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer to your **first** question.

If you want to update an Entity's property everytime that entity is updated you can use [`@PreUpdate`](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PreUpdate) annotation.

Lets say you have a `User` entity with `lastUpdatedDate` as one of its properties.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    ...

    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    ...

    //Setters getters 

    @PreUpdate
    public void updatedAt() {
        this.lastUpdatedDate= new Date();
    }

}
```

With that annotation you dont have to **explicitly** update `lastUpdatedDate` everytime you update `user` entity.

Also look [`@PrePersist`](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PrePersist) annotation that helps you automatically populate entity properties before persisting it.

> Answer to your second question

Currently this is not possible in `spring-data-jpa`. There is a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209) for this in JIRA which is still under investigation by the `Spring` team.

However if you want a workaround you can checkout a simple criteria query example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).